# Add column values together in jqGrid and insert into label

Tags: html, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid inside of a div `orderForm` that can have a verifying number of rows added to it by a user.

What I would like to do is: whenever a user adds a row to the jqGrid, the totals in the `TOTAL_LINE_AMOUNT` column are added together and inserted into the label `Subtotal`

```
 $('#orderForm).jqGrid({
        data: details,
        datatype: 'local',
        colNames: ['ID', 'QUANTITY', 'MODEL_ORDER_NUM', 'DESCRIPTION', 'PRICE_EACH', 'TOTAL_LINE_AMOUNT'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'DETAIL_RECORD_ID', index: 'DETAIL_RECORD_ID', sorttype: 'string' },
            { name: 'QUANTITY', index: 'QUANTITY', sorttype: 'string' },
            { name: 'MODEL_ORDER_NUM', index: 'MODEL_ORDER_NUM', sorttype: 'string' },
            { name: 'DESCRIPTION', index: 'DESCRIPTION', sorttype: 'string' },
            { name: 'PRICE_EACH', index: 'PRICE_EACH', sorttype: 'string' },
            { name: 'TOTAL_LINE_AMOUNT', index: 'TOTAL_LINE_AMOUNT', sorttype: 'string' }
        ],
        search: true,
        onSelectRow: LoadInput,
        loadonce: false,
        jsonReader: { cell: '' },
        sortname: 'DETAIL_RECORD_ID',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        sortable: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        hiddengrid: false,
        caption: 'Detail Records'
    });
```

UPDATE: Here is how I load data into my grid

```
Form.Controller.orderForm = new function () {
  var _detailRecordId = 1;
  this.Create = function () {
    var requestData = Controller.GetRequestData();
    requestData.orderForm.push({
        DETAIL_RECORD_ID: "T" + _detailRecordId++,
        REQUEST_RECORD_ID: requestData.REQUEST_RECORD_ID,
        QUANTITY: $('#orderForm_QUANTITY_INPUT').val(),
        MODEL_ORDER_NUM: $('#orderForm_MODEL_ORDER_NUM_INPUT').val(),
        DESCRIPTION: $('#orderForm_DESCRIPTION_INPUT').val(),
        PRICE_EACH: $('#orderForm_PRICE_EACH_INPUT').val(),
        TOTAL_LINE_AMOUNT: $('#orderForm_TOTAL_LINE_AMOUNT_INPUT').text()
    });
    Form.View.orderFrom.LoadGrid(requestData.orderForm);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't show which editing mechanism your are using with jqGrid so it is hard to say on which event you should subscribe (most porobably it should be either `jqGridInlineAfterSaveRow` or `jqGridAddEditAfterComplete`).

Getting the sum of column is very simple as jqGrid has a ready to use method for this:

```
var subTotal = $('#orderForm').jqGrid('getCol', 'TOTAL_LINE_AMOUNT', false, 'sum');
```

Depending of what kinf of HTML element your label is you should be able to set its text with one of following:

```
$('#Subtotal').text(subTotal);
```

or

```
$('#Subtotal').val(subTotal);
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  I had been trying to iterate through each row and add the value to a running total but it wasn't working well.  I will post the way I load data to the grid incase someone has a similar question in the future.